# optimal lending levels

Tags: money-supply, banking, regulation

Many ratios are mentioned to allude to what caps the amount of money a bank could lend. But none is really convincing. Usually debt ratio and solvability (Basel) ratio are mentioned. Elsewhere there is talk about taking multiples of deposits.

I have come across a response here which sets the limitation to be the amount in excess reserves where the inter-bank settlement takes place. How about the Bank funding itself at a lower rate (than the lending rate) in the open market and then pumping that amount back to its excess reserves? As long as the bank handles well the credit and liquidity risks that game could last for long.

Which rational is put forward to set the optimal amount of lent money in a retail bank?

Comment: This may be of interest: https://files.stlouisfed.org/files/htdocs/publications/page1-econ/2021/09/17/teaching-the-linkage-between-banks-and-the-fed-r-i-p-money-multiplier_SE.pdf